# dell xps 17 l702x Nvidia GT 555M (optimus)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, nvidia-optimus

I know there are some topics about getting Nvidia drivers to work on the Dell XPS 17 (l702X). I have read them all and tried several approaches.

Every time it results in re-installing Ubuntu because it won´t boot anymore.
I really like Ubuntu and don´t want to go back to windows even if i can´t get the video drivers installed.

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 on my system, what do i do step by step to get the drivers running on my system?

Kind regards, Paul

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop you have. Below are my notes from a year+ ago which are really just a summary from the other posts here on AskUbuntu. You may need to change the header version number to what you have installed.

What puzzles me though is what you mean by, your computer won't boot. Do you get a blinking cursor, a login, or the computer truly hangs? You may want to post some additional info here to get more feedback.

The default nvidia drivers do not work with the Optimus chipset (no menu, launcher etc.)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

and reboot after installation

To test bumblebee support, execute

```
sudo optirun
```